# How to setup an application level livedata observer pattern

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

**Background**

I have multiple ways to get data from server, such as background polling and server push. These items may be contain same item.when data is ready, I insert these data into database with Android Room. when the insert item have exist in database, I will abort the item. I expect to get notify when these data insert success, so I use livedata in the Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface WordDao {


    @Query("SELECT * from word_table where isNew = 0")
    LiveData<List<Word>> getAlphabetizedWords();

    @Insert
    void insert(List<Word> word);

    @Update
    void update(List<Word> words);

}
```

In the `application` code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    wordRepository = WordRepository.getInstance(this);
    wordRepository.getAllWords().observeForever(new DatabaseObserver(this));
}
```

In the `DatabaseObserver`, I receive data change notify. I will handle these data, then I will set one property of the class(set `isNew = 1`) to indicate that the item has been handled. At the same time, that handle keep the later insert will not notify old insert data.

**My Question**

1. Is this pattern using `observeForever()` will be worked as expect?
2. When I write the demo code, I encounter that the `DatabaseObserver`'s `onChanged` method receive same item list. After I change my code like [this](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1), the problem is still there. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: You want to create a global LiveData which you can listen from anywhere and get notified whenever it get's updated from any place?

Comment: @RohanKandwal yeah.

Comment: @penkzhou I haven't use LiveData to this extent, but Flowable works for sure. And you can subscribe to it anywhere, any number of times. If you are ready to shift to RX, may be I can help.

Comment: @penkzhou In that case, wordRepository.getAllWords() should return a LiveData right? Just make that LiveData as public global field and obsever on that LiveData from any activity/service/fragment.

Comment: Are you sure you need observeForever? You will get IllegalArgumentException if that data is already observed, and need to manually call removeObserver().
About the data you insert, use OnConflictStrategy or apply indeces with unique set to true, so you don't need manual checks.

Comment: @lomza I am observing in the Application level,not activity level.